# C++ Passing a Multi-D Array to a Function

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I want to manipulate a 2x2 array A to a function, by reference, so my function prototype is:

```
void myFunction( int A[][2] );
```

I'm assuming that what is actually passed to the function is just a pointer to the first element (as with 1D arrays). So inside the function I make an assignment such as:

```
(*(A+1))[1] = 2;
```

To will change the value of the element `A[1][1]` (even after my function returns).

Given that `C++` passes arrays to functions by reference automatically in this way, there doesn't seem to be a need to explicitly pass a pointer to the array in my function. But if I wanted to do this, would the correct syntax for my function prototype, and the analogue of the assignment above, respectively, be as follows?

```
void myFunction( int (*A)[][2] );
```

and

```
(*(*A+1))[1] = 2;
```

Comment: How is this array created in main?

Comment: Do not overcomplicate matters.`A[1][1]` is all you need.

Comment: The matrix will be defined in main as a maze, so I want to be able to change certain elements of it as the user passes through the maze. This I want to do via a recursive function that takes the matrix as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If your decl is:

```
void myFunction( int A[][2] );
```

you access the array like this:

```
A[1][1] = 2;
```

And this doesnt change when you use C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that what is actually passed to the function is just a pointer to the first element (as with 1D arrays)

This is correct.  Your prototype is equivalent to:

```
void myFunction( int (*A)[2] )
```

---

> So inside the function I make an assignment such as...

You don't need to do that.  You can just do:

```
A[1][1] = 2;
```

(it's equivalent to what you wrote).

---

> Given that C++ passes arrays to functions by reference automatically in this way...

Be careful on terminology there ;)  Passing something by reference has a specific meaning in C++, and this is not it!  It is accurate to say that the array decays to a pointer to its first element, and this pointer is passed by value.

---

> But if I wanted to do this, would the correct syntax for my function prototype, and the analogue of the assignment above, respectively, be as follows?

No; that won't compile.  A pointer must be to a *complete* type; you need array size information.  So your prototype would have to be something like:

```
void myFunction( int (*A)[7][2] )
```

And again, you can simplify the array access:

```
(*A)[1][1] = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful. referring to your last example, then, it seems I can make life easier for myself by just passing my matrix as a regular array to the function, is that right? So the array name A is a pointer to a 2D array, and I can refer to (and change within my function) the matrix elements via the normal syntax (e.g A[1][1] = ... )?

Comment: I assume the array name A is regarded by C++ as a pointer to the first element of the array A[0] (i.e. the first row of my matrix)?

Comment: @OliKlima: In any circumstance where the array decays to a pointer (which is most circumstances), yes, it's `&A[0]` (which in this case, is the first row of your 2D array).

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays are not implemented as nested arrays in C++, but as contiguous blocks, which is also why you must specify all dimensions but the first statically. So you should basically treat such an array as a 1D array with syntactic sugar for index computation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that he just want to know what would it be the correct sintax to pass a pointer to a multidimensional array in c++:

```
void myFunction( int (*A)[10][2] )
{
    cout<<(*A)[0][0];//prints 123
}
int main()
{
    int A[10][2];
    A[0][0] = 123;
    myFunction(&A);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
void myFunction(int (&A)[2][2]) {
    A[1][1] = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call it in main function

myfunction(&myarray);

and the function prototype is

myfunction(int (*a)[2][2])